# Stochastic Question: $d \int B_s ds = ?$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Stochastic Question: $d \int_0^t B_s ds = ?$

$B_s$ is the standard Brownian motion at time $s$. This is an Ito integral. Operator $d$ is defined in the standard Ito sense.

For those who understands this question, this background is plenty. I know at least one other people who agrees.

Comment: Is $B$ a Brownian motion starting at the origin? Do we understand the stochastic integral in the Itô's sense?

Comment: Yes and Yes Thanks Dante.

Comment: The problem is not the mismatch between your question and the tags but the lack of background, context and definitions. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) how to write a good question. Of course, you can edit your question to try to obtain the remotion of the on hold condition

Answer (score 3):

Notation such as $dX_t=B_t\,dt$ is just shorthand for
$$
X_t = X_0 + \int_0^t B_s\,ds
$$
So if $X_t = \int_0^t B_s\,ds$, then $dX_t=B_t\,dt$. Or, in other words,
$$
d\left({\int_0^t B_s\,ds}\right) = B_t\,dt,
$$
simply because that's what the notation means.

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks!